# Getting values out of string

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I have a variable with string as below

```
name=@col1, zip_cd=@col2, district=@col3, city=@col4
```

column list may increase.

I need below output

```
@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4
```

Comment: Another option without `awk`: `echo "name=@col1, zip_cd=@col2, district=@col3, city=@col4" | grep -o @.... | tr '\n' ',' | head -c-1` (or `echo "name=@col1, zip_cd=@col2, district=@col3, city=@col4" | grep -o @.... | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/.$/\n/'`)

Answer (score 1):

If your only goal is to print all the values of the variables (i.e. literally `@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4`), use an array:

```
$ array=($name $zip_cd $district $city)
```

Output:

```
$ oIFS="$IFS" # save IFS for later
$ IFS=","
$ echo ${array[*]}
@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4
$ IFS="$oIFS"`enter code here`
```

If you're looking to load columns into the variables then print them:

```
$ line="foo bar qaz qux"
$ oIFS="$IFS" # save IFS for later
$ IFS=" " # space, if $line has spaces/tabs, convert them into single spaces below
$ line=`sed 's/\s\+/ / <<< $line`
$ array=($line)
$ IFS="," # for display
$ echo ${array[*]}
foo,bar,qaz,qux
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ myvar='name=@col1, zip_cd=@col2, district=@col3, city=@col4'


$ echo $myvar
name=@col1, zip_cd=@col2, district=@col3, city=@col4

$ echo $myvar | awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){split($i,a,"=");printf("%s,",a[2])}}'
@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var='name=@col1, zip_cd=@col2, district=@col3, city=@col4'

newvar=$( printf '%s' "$variable" | awk 'BEGIN { RS=" "; ORS=""; FS="=" } { print $2 }' )

printf '%s\n' "$newvar"
@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4
```

The `awk` script treats the input as a series of records delimited by spaces bu setting the record separator (`RS`) ta a space character (the default is a newline).  This gives us the following records:

```
name=@col1,
zip_cd=@col2,
district=@col3,
city=@col4
```

It also divides each of these records into fields on the `=` character (by setting `FS`, the field separator), which gives us the records conseptually divided into columns like this:

```
name     @col1,
zip_cd   @col2,
district @col3,
city     @col4
```

Then it prints the second field of each record.  In doing so, it uses an empty record separator (the default output record separator, `ORS`, is a newline), which gives us the desired output.

I put the output from `awk` into a new variable and printed it to standard output.

Comment: @ManojY Good! If one of the answers solves your issue, please consider [accepting that
answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
echo "name=@col1, zip_cd=@col2, district=@col3, city=@col4" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[^=,]*=";OFS=""} {$1=$1}1'
```

The field separator `FS` is set to the left side of the `key=value` construction, including the `=` sign.

The output field separator is blank since there is already a comma after the value.

The `{$1=$1}` is triggering `awk` to apply the `FS` and `OFS` on the whole record.

At last, the `1` is triggering the default action in awk: print the record.

Answer (score 0):

## Bash

```
VAR='name=@col1, zip_cd=@col2, district=@col3, city=@col4'
echo "$VAR" |
while IFS= read -r line
do
   IFS='=,'; set -f; set -- $line
   while case $# in 0 ) break ;; esac
   do
      shift
      printf '%s' "${1}${2+,}"
      shift
      ${1+':'} echo
   done
done
```

## Sed

```
echo "$VAR" |
sed -ne '
   H;g
   :loop
      s/\(\n\)[^=]*=\([^,]*,\{0,1\}\)/\2\1/
   tloop
   P
'
```

## Perl

```
echo "$VAR" |
perl -F'/=|,/' -lpe '
   $_ = join ",", grep { $a++ % 2 } @F;
'
```